# php default header

Tags: php, header

Is there any specific header I should be serving for plain php pages?

I'm not redirecting the user or anything like that and my markup already has a `doctype` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Do I also need to start with a PHP `header()`? Is there anything specific that it should have?

Comment: Non is mandatory but you could use a Content-Type header if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`header()` is for sending HTTP headers.  If you're asking, you probably don't need it yet, though you could get rid of your `meta` by doing:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Remember that `header()` directives must all come before any content has been sent, otherwise you will get errors.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using php to render html, then use text/html.

usually your webserver actually knows to do this already and explicitly setting the header content type is unnecessary. At least this is the case with apache.

Comment: Should I be doing that at all?

Comment: oh, the answer is no because of the second part of my response. UNLESS you know your page is being rendered improperly because mime type handling by the webserver is incorrect

Comment: Your MIME type is _probably_ being handled correctly, but sometimes you want to define the charset.  Defining both in Content-Type (whichever way you do so) generally works well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to serve PHP with anything :) You are all set with your meta UTF8, assuming you're outputting your PHP in the same fashion.

Comment: If you are curious you can see the MIME type served up @ http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-mimetype.htm -- But this has to do with your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To serve PHP pages we use a header() function this way

http://www.google.com/"); ?>
However remember that that you cannot have any HTML output before the header is sent.
You can also try using one of this [alternatives.](http://www.techyv.com/questions/calling-functions-using-php#new)